# Remove many table values AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to figure out how to remove all table values from 'dzviokli' that hasnt got same 'majaId' with 'maja.ID'

This is my html

```
<tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="maja in majas">

            <td>{{maja.numurs}}</td>
            <td>{{maja.iela}}</td>
            <td>{{maja.pilseta}}</td>
            <td>{{maja.valsts}}</td>
            <td>{{maja.pasts}}</td>



        <td><button ng-click="linkedDzivokli(maja)" class="dzivoklap poga">Dzivokli</button></dt>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
<tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="dz in dzivokli">
            <td>{{dz.numurs}}</td>
            <td>{{dz.stavs}}</td>
            <td>{{dz.ist_sk}}</td>
            <td>{{dz.iedz_sk}}</td>
            <td>{{dz.pilna_plat}}</td>
            <td>{{dz.dziv_plat}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

This is my js. The maja.ID is maja from another database and it contais value ID. Table dzivokli has value 'MajaId' and it is linked with table 'maja' value ID.

```
 $http.get("http://localhost:20988/api/maja").success(function (response){$scope.majas = response;});
$http.get("http://localhost:20988/api/dzivoklis").success(function(response){$scope.dzivokli = response;});
var sar = $scope.dzivokli;
            var index = maja.ID;
            lala(sar,index);            
}   
    function lala(sar,index)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < sar.length; i++)
        {
            if(sar[i].MajaId != index)
            {
                var x = sar.indexOf(sar[i]);
            }
            sar.splice(x,1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not the answer for your question but: 1. Start using english variable names 2. Start using JSHint 3. Start using JSLint

Answer (score 0):

Test with this:

```html
for (var i = 0; i < maja.length; i++) {
 seekAndDestroy($scope.dzivokli,majaId, maja[i].ID);
}


function seekAndDestroy(obj, key, value){
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (obj[i][key] == value) {
            obj.splice(i, 1);
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Thanks jlizanab for answering :)

Here is my js

```
$scope.linkedDzivokli = function(maja) 
{   
        $http.get("http://localhost:####/api/dzivoklis").success(function(response){
        var garums = response.length;
        for (var i = 0; i != garums; i++) 
        {   
            if (response[i].MajaId == maja.ID) {}
            else
            {
                response.splice(response.indexOf(response[i]), 1);
                garums = garums - 1;
                i = i - 1;
            }
        }
        $scope.dzivokli = response;
    });
}
```